# Why strange lines displaying in collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am currently working in creating a custom calendar where I tried to display Seven cells in a row , But unfortunately some lines occurs randomly can any one guide the error.I have attached the screen shot

[image: Screen shot of the calendar page]

I have attached the sample code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let s = CGSize(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 7), height: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 7))
    return s
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return numDays+weekday
}
```

Comment: Please change collection view background

Comment: As @Lalit said. Change the colors of your collectionView.backgroundColor /collectionViewCell.contentView.backgroundColor and you will see where the spacing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by  `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0 // OR change as you need
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0 // OR change as you need
    }
```

Comment: Change in IB-> show the size inspector -> Min Spacing -> for cell = 0 and for line = 0

Comment: Tofaani I have already done this changes but still facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour appears when you compute the size of your cell.

Hear, you are doing :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let s = CGSize(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 7), height: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 7))
    return s
}
```

The cell's size may not be rounded, therefor the runtime tries to do its best to fill the collection view with your constraints but end up with these little flaws.

Comment: Can I know how to fix the issue ?